# Close/Dispose on FileStream

Tags: c#, filestream, idisposable

I've got a bit of code in a product I am supporting that copies files:

```
using(System.IO.FileStream sourceFS = new System.IO.FileStream(sourcePath, System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read, System.IO.FileShare.Read))
            {
                using(System.IO.FileStream targetFS = new System.IO.FileStream(targetPath, System.IO.FileMode.Create, System.IO.FileAccess.Write, System.IO.FileShare.Read))
                {
                    while((read = sourceFS.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                    {
                        targetFS.Write(buffer, 0, read);
                    }

                    targetFS.Flush();
                    targetFS.Close();
                }

                sourceFS.Close();
            }
```

Unfortunately, the users are reporting an exception informing us that the destination file is in use by another process. I've asked if there is a chance that someone has the file open (it's an Excel file) - apparently not...

So, I put the thinking cap on... Is it possible we are leaving the destination file with a file lock against it? The only way I can see for targetFS not to be closed would be require both:

1. An exception to be thrown within the inner using block, and
2. The Dispose method not to actually close the stream.

This sounded unlikely to me, but ever curious I used dotPeek from JetBrains to disassemble the Dispose method on the FileStream class - which doesn't seem to do all that much really - I'm guessing its "close" behaviour is provided by disposing of the handle...

In essence though - the question is this - can anyone spot how this might be leaving a file with a lock against it?

Comment: Performance tip: don't flush or close explicitly. Neither of them do any good, and flush does harm.

Comment: You don't need the flush()/close() parts with using. Also both using statements are fine, you should look for the problem somewhere else.

Comment: You say that the ctor of the destination FileStream throws an exception. At the same time you say that you might have left the destination open. But how could you have left it open if you never opened it successfully? Look elsewhere. This code is fine.

Comment: why is the destination file has `FileShare.Read`?

Comment: Why don't you use File.Copy()? FileCopy(sourcePath, targetPath, true);

Comment: In your application or in another application, if you use OLE and COM to access Excel, and if you don't properly take care of destroying Excel objects at the end, you get processes hanging around specially in case of abnormal ends. This could cause your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your input everyone... 

As to why the code has Fileshare.Read, I don't know - I didn't write it...

Comment: These sorts of problems, particularly if they are transient and hard to reproduce, are often associated with badly written virus checkers. Some virus checkers are very aggressive about noticing that a file has been used recently and then lock it and scan it *as soon as possible*. This is a rude thing to do, as a file that has been used recently is likely to be used again soon; a more polite checker would put the file on a list for processing, say, a billion nanoseconds in the future, when it is more likely that the legitimate owners are all hands-off the file.

Comment: Thanks everyone... 

At the end of the day, the actual issue turned out to be some muppet in an obscure department who had the file open - for weeks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look elsewhere. This code is fine. Not sure what else to say about it. `using` is meant for exactly this use case - failsafe disposal.

Investigate using Process Explorer which process is holding a handle to the file in question.